# Iphone Picker view is loaded before urlconnection finishes, and I don't want it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiview

I have a picker view and a web service connection in my UIView, I want to load my picker views datasource with the data I receive from web, but program always first tries to load pickerview and then it jumps to connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection method.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an NSMutableArray. Fill the array when your data is available and call  `[pickerView reloadAllComponents]`. This should call the following method:
`(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component` in which you can reload the titles.